# Visibility of element function in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have made a search bar that I want to show when user will click on search image that is list item as

```
<li class="item" onclick="showSearch()"><img id="search" src="images/search.png" ></li>
```

I set the visibility to hidden in HTML as

```
<div id="bar_search" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

have a function as

```
function showSearch () {
    document.getElementById("bar_search").style.visibility = "visible"; 
}
```

but when i click on list item it does not show however hidden property working fine.

where I'm making mistake please tell me, thanks

**Update:**
content in the div

```
<div id="bar_search" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <img id="searchbar" src="images/searchBar.png">
        <div id="searchDec">
            <input type="text">
            <button ><b>Search</b></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsbin.com/hemeticupu

Comment: There is no obvious error in the code. Do you get any error message?

Comment: have you checked that there is an element with an id attribute `bar_search`? You can always use `console.log` to see what's happening. For instance `console.log(document.getElementById('bar_search').length));`if not 1 or more then there are no elements with the id `bar_search`.

Comment: Place your code at the end of the html, before closing body tag... Btw, what is vanilla JS alternative for $(document) ready? :)

Comment: @nevermind — Why? The event handler is bound with an `onclick` attribute.

Comment: I have an error showSearch that is the name of function, not found error in the html where I call the function but in the above code you can see I defined it.

Comment: @sourRaspberry: to have more than one could also be the problem

Comment: @Quentin, my mistake... something went wrong with fiddle... :)

Comment: is there content to show in your div?

Comment: yes when I remove the hidden property content show there

Comment: @InzimamTariqIT — It is found in Daniel's live demo. Whatever your problem is, the code you've shared so far doesn't include it.

Comment: check I updated the question with div contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine maybe you have syntax error in the same page

```js
function showSearch() {
    document.getElementById("bar_search").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<li class="item" onclick="showSearch()">
    <img id="search" src="https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IconsPage?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=search.png">
</li>
<div id="bar_search" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img id="search" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6BXa.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the property through your style sheet and see if you can't get it to change with the event-handler.

```
    <node class="hidden" onclick=toggleVisibilty()"></node>
```

Or if your not opposed to using jQuery, then you could always use the toggle method, so as to toggle the class that way.

> http://api.jquery.com/toggle/